# C++ cannot initialize temporary with initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class defining a data structure (let's call it A) and I want to create a simple iterator for it with some basic operations (next, prev, element, valid...).

Iterator.h

```
#include "A.h"

class Iterator {
private:
    A* a;
    int current;
public:
    Iterator(A* _a) : a(_a) { current = 0; }
};
```

In my class A, I created a function iterator() which should return an iterator and I thought about something like this:

A.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Iterator.h"

class A {
private:
    int some_data;
public:
    friend class Iterator;
    A(int x) : some_data(x) {}
    ~A();

    Iterator iterator() { return Iterator{ this }; }
};
```

But I get this error: "Cannot initialize temporary of type "Iterator" with initializer list". All I want to do is to create and return an Iterator object from the iterator() function in class A.

Note: I have these classes in separate headers in my project. I use Visual Studio.

Comment: You need to write a minimal example sufficient to reproduce the error. Also specify which compiler and flags you're using.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: Hope it's ok now...

Comment: Still cannot reproduce, using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Just curious, why do you initialize current in the ctor body instead of like the A* a?

Answer (score 0):

You have a cyclic dependency. Your `A.h` includes `Iterator.h` and vice versa. The result, due to the `#pragma once` not doing quite what you expected, is that the compiler attempts to compile

```
class Iterator {
private:
    A* a;
    int current;
public:
    Iterator(A* _a) : a(_a) { current = 0; }
};

class A {
private:
    int some_data;
public:
    A(int x) : some_data(x) {}
    ~A();

    Iterator iterator() { return Iterator{ this }; }
};
```

This fails, because it uses `A` before `A` has been defined. It fails with very confusing error messages, but you were only looking at the *last* of them, whereas the first error message at least points to where the problem is.

Instead of having `Iterator.h` include `A.h`, provide a forward declaration of `A`:

```
class A;
```